# centos 7 handling gitlab and mailserver

Tags: centos, security, postfix, gitlab

i'm quite noob with servers so here i'm asking a question.

i just installed a centos 7 on a vps. I installed gitlab and postfix on it. is it safe to handle both mail server and gitlab on it? everytime i log via ssh i get a message like this

There were 51 failed login attempts since the last successful login.

isn't it too much? i installed firewalld with basic configuration. 
where eventually can i learn more about configuring all this in a safe way? am i doing wrong installing both postfix mail server and gitlab on the same machine? i read basic tutorials but i think i need some best practice info...

Thanks

Comment: This is not a problem to use 4/5 services on same machine ; until you have no ports conflicts of course.  A good practice is to apply hardening procedures after your install.  (you will find tutos for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's okay to have two or more services on one server, if there is enough resources.

About login attempts, you will have a lot errors like this if you doesn't change port for `sshd` or allow access to port 22 for whitelisted addresses.

If you want to secure your machine, you could use [this checklist](https://security.utexas.edu/os-hardening-checklist/linux-7). It's for Red Hat 7, but checklist applicable to CentOS 7.

Comment: thank you so much! i'll do it right now. and thanks for the checklist... seems a bit hard but very interesting. i'll study it carefully! any other hint or suggest? thanks again

Comment: @AnjaDell, this checklist made from this [document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/index). So you could read it before applying checklist.